# Oracle : How to update only the lastest row in oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have the following Oracle database. Employee table is in descending order using order by clause. The table columns are examples just to explain the scenario.

```
S.no    Time_to_complete   Project     employee_id    
3       23                 project3      xx
2       22                 project2      xx
1       34                 project1      xx
```

I need to update only the latest record in database ie

```
S.no    Time_to_complete    Project   employee_id  
3       25(updated)         project3      xx
```

NOTE: this update is part of a function and I only have access to employee_id

How can I update, only the latest row in Oracle?

```
update employee set time_to_complete=25 where employee_id=xx and rownum=1 order by s.no desc
```

return

```
S.no    time_to_complete    Project   employee_id  
1       25(updated)         project1      xx
```

Comment: What is the primary key in your table?  Is `s.no` unique?

Comment: What does "latest" mean?  By your example, I am assuming max s.no, but "latest" could mean "last record updated" which could be any of them, and without an updated_time column, you couldn't know which one it was.

Comment: sorry i forgot. S.no is a primary key and its auto incremented whenever a new data is entered .

Comment: The database is a concurrent environment. So usually the term "latest" has no meaning as there might be other sessions touching the same table at the same moment.

Comment: yeah you are correct. but my application is a single user right now. Soon i will try for concurrent data insertion and updating the latest transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update employee e
   set e.time_to_complete = 25 
 where e.s_no = (select max(e2.s_no) from employee e2 where e2.employee_id = xx)
```

Comment: It could be that in 12c a more efficient solution is possible, by using an "order by s_no desc" and a limit clause. Can't test it though.